# .NET HttpWebRequest & SendChunked: how to send a large content?

Tags: .net, stream, httpwebrequest, chunks

I am writing a console application that must copy large SQL tables from a database to another by sending data through a web service. Because the tables may be very large, and because they cannot (and should not) be stored entirely in memory, I am using a DataReader to read the data sequentially and was hoping to stream it to the webservice.

In order to do this, I have my web service declared like so:

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="{Id}/SendData", method:="PUT", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)>
Sub UploadData(ByVal Id As String, ByVal DataStream As Stream)
```

In my console application, I am creating the request like so:

```
    Dim tRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL_WEBSERVICES & "DataLoad/" & _Id & "/SendData")
    tRequest.SendChunked = True
    tRequest.Method = "PUT"
    tRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
```

Then I open the request stream and write data like so:

```
While tSqlReader.Read
    ' Check if a new chunk of data must be created
    If tRows Is Nothing Then
        tRows = New List(Of Object)
    End If
    ' Fill chunk with data
    tRowValues = New Object(tSqlReader.FieldCount - 1) {}
    tSqlReader.GetValues(tRowValues)
    tRows.Add(tRowValues)
    ' Check if chunk is full and must be sent
    If tRows.Count = CHUNK_ROWS_COUNT Then
        ' Write data to the request stream
        tDataChunk = SerializeToByteArray(tRows)
        tStream.Write(tDataChunk, 0, tDataChunk.Length)
        tRows = Nothing
        tDataChunk = Nothing
    End If
End While
' Write final data to the request stream
If tRows IsNot Nothing Then
    tDataChunk = SerializeToByteArray(tRows)
    tStream.Write(tDataChunk, 0, tDataChunk.Length)
End If
```

Then I close the request stream and call tRequest.GetResponse().

SerializeToByArray is the following function:

```
Private Function SerializeToByteArray(ByVal pObject As Object) As Byte()
    If pObject Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Dim tBinaryFormatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
    Dim tMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
    tBinaryFormatter.Serialize(tMemoryStream, pObject)
    Return tMemoryStream.ToArray
End Function
```

My problem is that the web service only receives the first chunk of data, e.g. if CHUNK_ROWS_COUNT = 5 then it only receives 5 rows of data. (I am aware that this is not the size of the chunks that HttpWebRequest will make).

My only guess would be that I am sending a number of serialized data packs through the stream, each encapsulated by some serialization headers and that therefore the deserialization process in the web service only finds and decapsulates the first one, but that's just an idea and I am not sure how to do it differently. I cannot serialize the whole content and send write it in chunks because the whole content does not fit in memory.

Any advice?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this in WCF with a manual HttpWebRequest.
WCF will handle chunks by itself, do not reinvent the wheel.

some greate articles :

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx

Do not forget to change reader quotas in wcf config

Comment: I know WCF should handle chunks just by settings SendChunked to true in the WebRequest, but I am not sure how to send large serialized data (data large enough that it can't fit all in memory and therefore can't be serialized in one shot). I'd like to know if I am doing it right or if must be done differently.